# How to access a object's attrbute by using string corresponding to name if object is attribute of some other object

Tags: python

I have 3 classes as below:-

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.var = v

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

I have created instances as 
c = C("required result")
b = B(c)
a = A(b)

>>> a.b.c.var
'required result'
```

Now I need to pass b.c.var as a string to some function and get the value of var similar to sample function as below -

```
`sample(a, 'b.c.var')` should return 'required result'`
```

What should be pythonic way to achieve this
This is my attempt :-

```
for attr in ('b', 'c', 'var'):
    a = getattr(a, attr)
>>> print a
required result
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on your problem? Having a more readable code would be your first step on having a more pythonic code.

Comment: Take a look at getattr (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and str.split (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: @WilliamFernandes I have update question with my attempt

Comment: What is the result of your attempt?

Comment: why not use a dictionary? `a = {'b':{'c':{'var':'required result'}}}`

Comment: @S.deMelo required result, updated question

Comment: so, you got the right result. that's all?

Comment: I just discovered `getattr` doesn't work for strings like `var.x`

Comment: So you're almost done, aren't you?  You just need to convert 'b.c.var' to ('b', 'c', 'var') using .split('.'), unless I'm missing something

Comment: I can find my answer by using split and getattr, Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [operator.attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) which takes a dotted name notation, eg:

```
from operator import attrgetter
attrgetter('b.c.var')(a)
# 'required result'
```

Then if you don't like that syntax, use it to make your `sample` function, eg:

```
def sample(obj, attribute):
    getter = attrgetter(attribute)
    return getter(obj)
```

From the documentation linked above, the `operator.attrgetter` uses the equivalent of the following code:

```
def attrgetter(*items):
    if any(not isinstance(item, str) for item in items):
        raise TypeError('attribute name must be a string')
    if len(items) == 1:
        attr = items[0]
        def g(obj):
            return resolve_attr(obj, attr)
    else:
        def g(obj):
            return tuple(resolve_attr(obj, attr) for attr in items)
    return g

def resolve_attr(obj, attr):
    for name in attr.split("."):
        obj = getattr(obj, name)
    return obj
```

So in fact - your original code was just trying to do the equivalent of `resolve_attr`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the more accurate way, I suppose. (using `try-except` construction):

```
...

c = C("required result")
b = B(c)
a = A(b)

def sample(obj, path):
    path_attrs = path.split('.')    # splitting inner attributes path
    inner_attr = None

    for p in path_attrs:
        try:
            inner_attr = getattr(inner_attr if inner_attr else  obj, p)
        except AttributeError:
            print('No %s field' % p)

    print(inner_attr)

sample(a, 'b.c.var')  # will output 'required result'
```